# node-mysql2 Finally block and connection.end() don't want to be invoked

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using this mysql package: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2

My current function:

```
const getDataFromTable = async (table) => {
console.info(`Exporting '${table.name}' table.`);
// prepare connection to MySQL
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: mysqlConfig.host,
    user: mysqlConfig.user,
    password: mysqlConfig.password,
    database: mysqlConfig.database
});


try {
    // Async query to database
    await connection.query(
        `SELECT * FROM \`${table.name}\` WHERE \`${table.idFieldName}\` >${lastIndex} ORDER BY ID ASC`,
        (err, results) => {
            console.debug(`Exported '${results.length}' records.`);


            if (Array.isArray(results) && results.length > 0) {
                convertArrayToCvs(results, table);
                lastIndex = results.pop().id;

                if (table.saveIndex) {
                    fs.writeFile(indexFileName, lastIndex, error => (error ? console.error(error) : null));
                }
            }
        }
    );
} finally {
    console.log('Connection end');
    await connection.end();
}
```

My problem is that **finally** block is skipped during script execute (**try** working properly). I tried lunch this same script without try catch finally block but I still had problem with **connection.end()** which is not working at all.

This function is invoking in **setInterval()** so I have to close every connection otherwise will be too many of them and this error will occur: *UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Too many connections*

Comment: why are you using await in connection.query function? It does not return any promise. Response you are getting in callback function. If you are only using connection.query function without using connection.connect function, query function takes care of opening the connection to the database and closing it.

Answer (score 0):

I handle the problem with the code below:

```
const getDataFromTable = async (table) => {
console.info(`Exporting '${table.name}' table.`);
// Prepare connection to MySQL
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: mysqlConfig.host,
    user: mysqlConfig.user,
    password: mysqlConfig.password,
    database: mysqlConfig.database
});

try {
    // Async query to database
    const [results] = await connection.query(`SELECT * FROM \`${table.name}\` WHERE \`${table.idFieldName}\` >${lastIndex} ORDER BY ID ASC`);

    console.debug(`Exported '${results.length}' records.`);


    if (Array.isArray(results) && results.length > 0) {
        convertArrayToCvs(results, table);
        lastIndex = results.pop().id;

        if (table.saveIndex) {
            fs.writeFile(indexFileName, lastIndex, error => (error ? console.error(error) : null));
        }
    }
} finally {
    await connection.end();
}
```